# 19th-century French "flash fiction" writer/journalist

Tags: french-language, identification-request

I'm trying to find the name of a fin-de-siècle writer/*feuilletoniste*/journalist who wrote very short fiction pieces based on crime stories in the Paris newspapers. A collection of these was published some time within the last ten years and was reviewed, or at least mentioned, in the *New York Review of Books* or the *London Review of Books*. Is there anyone out there who knows who I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely candidate is [Félix Fénéon (22 June 1861 – 29 February 1944)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9lix_F%C3%A9n%C3%A9on). A collection of his short fiction *Novels in Three Lines* (*Nouvelles en trois lignes* in French) was translated by Luc Sante and published in 2007. A [review by Julian Barnes](https://www.lrb.co.uk/the-paper/v29/n19/julian-barnes/behind-the-gas-lamp) appeared in the *London Review of Books* on 4 October 2007.

(["Nouvelle"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouvelle) does not mean "novel"; it refers to a very short narrative form; "short story" would be a more accurate translation. As far as I know, the term "flash fiction" did not exist during Fénéon's lifetime, even though the genre already existed.)